# Find the direction of curve at the point $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus

Find the direction of $y= x/(1+x^2)$ at the point $(0,0)$.

I couldn't find the solution of the questions asked here. Really thankful for your kind helpfulness.

Comment: What is the meaning of direction of a function at a point?

Comment: i mean directional derivative of function

Comment: Wait! This is a single variable function. There's no directional derivative in this case (or it's trivially the value of the derivative at $x=0$).

Comment: actually I translated from my language to English. i tried to comment it but could'nt.  what else can be asked which is explained via "Direction"? can it be direction vector?

Comment: Won't a double derivative be sufficient?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by direction though. Do you mean if the function is sloping upward or downward?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i get you right but if you mean the tangent of the set of points fullfilling your equation the direction at $0,0$ is
$$
(1, \frac{d y}{d x}(1))
$$

Comment: Would be my answer as well.

Comment: how can i obtain the result? is it standard form?

Comment: Considering $c(t)=(t,(f(t))$ the velocity vector is $\frac{d}{dt}c(t)=(1,f'(t).)$

Comment: If you imagine the graph of your funciton there then you can define the tangent space at every point which has all the vectors that are tangential to that graph. Thats what i would understand as ,,the direction'' and my solution is one of the points in the tangent space at (0,0). You get all those points in the tangent space by taking multiples of this solution.

Comment: direction vector and is this same?

Comment: No its not. You only have a function $y: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. If you would take the direction vector that would live in $\mathbb R$ and therefore would be a scalar. That doesnt make too much sence here. Thats why i am not sure what you mean. But if you were to take the function of @MichaelHoppe then its the direction vector of that function at $0$.